# What is the point of giving my Section Manager evaluators if she will just pick her own for performance reviews?

Tags: professionalism, performance-reviews

## Background

At my company, whenever evaluations are conducted, the Section Managers ask everyone for a list of evaluators to help in creating a summary of that worker's contributions.  They ask for 2 - 3 evaluators, at least on of which must be a direct report.  Over the past few performance reviews, I gave my direct manager (different from the section manager), my mentor, and someone I work closely with.  However, there has been times where my Section Manager does something along the lines of:

"I checked in with a different set of evaluators"

And she doesn't really elaborate more than that.  Or she doesn't say it explicitly, but suggests that she talked to people on my team who I did not list as evaluators, implying that her analysis came from people who I did not tell her to look at.  This is concerning me and I don't know how to respond to it professionally. Indeed, I don't know why it is even worth me giving evaluators to her. This prompted my question.

## Question

Why should I even bother giving my Section Manager a list of evaluators if she forms her feedback from people who I did not list as evaluators?

Comment: What did she say when you asked her about this? We can't read her mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why should I even bother giving my Section Manager a list of evaluators if she forms her feedback from people who I did not list as evaluators?

You're giving her suggestions - doesn't sound like she's obligated to adhere strictly to those suggestions.

> Or she doesn't say it explicitly, but suggests that she talked to people on my team who I did not list as evaluators, implying that her analysis came from people who I did not tell her to look at.

I'd hope she is - otherwise she'd be doing a pretty poor job. Her job is to get as complete a picture of your performance as she can. If she just spoke with people you suggested and went purely off that she would risk missing potentially serious issues. I'm not saying there *are* serious issues with your performance, but it's her job to look for them.

> This is concerning me and I don't know how to respond to it professionally.

Unless you're particularly concerned about what these people would say I don't think it's anything to be concerned about, or indeed that it requires any "response".

If you **do** have concerns about what these people might have said, e.g. one of them has an issue with you then you can cross that bridge when you come to it.

> I don't know why it is even worth me giving evaluators to her.

erm.. *because she asked for them?* It's not exactly an unreasonable request - sure you can refuse and pout about it if you want but to what end?

Even if she is checking in with different people it doesn't mean that the evaluators you provided her with were a waste of time - for all you know it was they who suggested she check in with the other parties.

Comment: Your answer is too clear cut. Maybe there's a rule at the company that really just the 3 people an employee wants to be assessed by are consulted? Some companies have precise rules for that, it's not always that the manager decides that on their own.

Comment: @BigMadAndy I can only assume the OP would have mentioned such a rule as it would have been *extremely* pertinent info.

Comment: For me this sounds as suggesting that there are clear rules for reviews: "At my company, whenever evaluations are conducted, the Section Managers ask everyone for a list of evaluators to help in creating a summary of that worker's contributions. They ask for 2 - 3 evaluators, at least on of which must be a direct report."

Answer (score 1):

> Why should I even bother giving my Section Manager a list of evaluators if she forms her feedback from people who I did not list as evaluators?

Because she is your manager and her request is not unreasonable.  Sure, you can refuse the request but that will probably not help with your evaluation.  Just because she takes feedback from someone you did not list does not mean that she is not taking feedback from the ones that you did list.  Usually, the more information available, the more accurate the evaluation will be.

If you are concerned about how the evaluation is conducted, you can ask to meet with your manager to discuss how they are conducted and share what your concerns are.  This may help you get a better understanding of the process at your company

Answer (score 1):

You should first check what the policies for that at your company are.

Of course, as others pointed out, your manager can consult whoever they want.

However, when it comes to formal performance reviews, some companies have clear, detailed rules for that. And yours sound as one of them if you are asked to provide names of three "evaluators" and there are even rules concerning who this should be.

Discuss the process with your manager or HR.

Comment: As a scientist, when I'm submitting a manuscript to a journal, I'm often asked to suggest reviewers. There are rules regarding who can (and more importantly cannot) be a reviewer. However, that doesn't imply a rule that these reviewers have to be chosen by the editor (and frequently they aren't). I'm having trouble following your logic here. I don't see any indication that there is a rule in this company that suggested "evaluators" have to be used.